# How to fix word HTML tabs?

Tags: xslt

When Microsoft Word saves document as HTML the tabs are aligned using spaces.
This results in a web page in which the text is not properly aligned.
Does anyone have an idea how to use `.XSLT` to fix this?
Such code might look like this:

```
<p><span>Open log ing screen           </span><span>(Opens log in screen)</span></p>
<p><span>Enter Username:                           </span><span>ivor</span></p>
<p><span>Password:                                      </span><span>Bbb</span></p>
```

Is it possible to calculate the length of the string in `pt` or `cm` or `em`, so that I could align the second span to the closest grid/tab value?

Comment: the tabs are aligned using spaces due to the encoding that MS Word auto slaps on files. If your coding in `.HTML` then use a proper programming IDE like Sublime >http://www.sublimetext.com/ otherwise you can make a Macro >> https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Record-or-run-a-macro-cd56fb86-d8b2-475c-ba39-9728389feeeb << to replace `____` (every four spaces) with a `\t` (tab) character.

Comment: You want me to create VBA Macro which replaces 4 spaces with tab character? But how would that help.? Wouldn't I still have the same problem if tabs are aligned either using space characters or tab characters?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. There are no tabs in HTML. You must use some other device to align your text, e.g. a table or CSS.

Comment: IMHO the best solution is to not use tabs. If you truly thought of the world of digital processing of information, you would realize it is not possible to "move over to the next position that I am suppose to stop at" ... especially considering there is no place to define "where to stop at".